# define CNN architecture and kernel size of CNN for 36 X 36 X 2 input shape

Tags: tensorflow, input, pytorch, conv-neural-network, kernel

In my dataset, I have 2D matrices. In this dataset, one datapoint represents two features and one targets. My each feature represnts one matrix of size 36 X 36. So bascially, I have one datapoint of size 36 X 36 X 2 as input and one scaler value as an output.

Since I have data in a 2D matrix form, I am aiming to use a CNN model. In my case, I would like to build a CNN for regression task.

My question is: is it possible to give an input of 36 X 36 X 2 to Convolutional Neural Network? If this is possible, then what will be my kernel size? I am less experienced in CNN. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can build a CNN with an input size of 36 X 36 X 2. In tensorflow you would use the layer.Conv2D(...) for this. Documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D

The kernel size is something you can choose as a network architect. To make it easy, you should start with a kernel size of (2, 2).

When using tensorflow, the start of your model definition will look something like this:

```py
input_layer = Input(shape=(32, 32, 2), name='input_layer')
x = Conv2D(4, (2, 2), strides=(1, 1))(input_layer)
x = Conv2D(4, (2, 2), strides=(1, 1))(x)

# etc...
```

In order to scale your 32x32x2 input you want to increase the stride. If you use stride of (2,2) you image dimensions will halve each layer.

If you are using a stride of (1,1), but a kernel size (2, 2) or larger, the convulsions will change the size of your input. In order to prevent this change you need to add padding. An example of padding would be:

```py
# conv layer that pads in order to keep layer input dimensions
Conv2D(8, (2, 2), strides=(1, 1), padding="same")
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please let me know why you have chosen shape=(32,32,2) since I have the size of one data point is 36, 36, 2?

Comment: So, the shape of the `Input(...)` layer must match that of your data. The `4` in `Conv2D` represents the same as the `2` in the Input, aka the number of filters. It is common for tasks like yours to downscale the image 32x32x2 --> 16x16x4, etc. Until you have a 1x1xF shape. Then you can take the sum/average over all values to get your scalar. It is best to not make large jumps on the number of filters, that is why I start with 4 right after the input layer. The more filters you have the more `features` your network can learn about the input data. Good Luck!